# Toggle card content for only direct child with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have about 9 cards on my site. Here is the structure of one card:

```
<div class="serviceCard">
  <div class="serviceContent">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
  <a class="serviceToggle">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

I am using the below jQuery to toggle the content of the card, but it's affecting all my cards since they all use the same class. How can I adjust my code so that it only affects the card that I am clicking on?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".serviceToggle").click(function(){
     jQuery(".serviceContent").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(".serviceToggle").on("click", function(e) { $(this).prev().toggle()});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `.click` function, you can use `jQuery(this)` to refer to the current element and `.find` other elements starting from there:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".serviceToggle").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent()
    .find(".serviceContent").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="serviceCard">
  <div class="serviceContent">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
  <a class="serviceToggle">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same can of course be done with Vanilla JavaScript and a delegated event listener. This will allow for dynamically added `.serviceCard`  elements:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  let btn=ev.target;
  if (btn.classList.contains("serviceToggle")){
   let divSt=btn.closest(".serviceCard").querySelector(".serviceContent").style;
   divSt.display=divSt.display==""?"none":"";
  }
})
```

```css
.serviceCard a {color:blue}
```

```html
<div class="serviceCard">
  <div class="serviceContent">
    blah blah blah first time
  </div>
  <a class="serviceToggle">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="serviceCard">
  <div class="serviceContent">
    blah blah blah second time
  </div>
  <a class="serviceToggle">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="serviceCard">
  <div class="serviceContent">
    blah blah blah third time
  </div>
  <a class="serviceToggle">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

I used `.closest()` instead of `.parent() (a function of the same name and functionality is also available in jQuery!) as it makes the script more tolerant towards possible layout changes in the HTML.